# Is the required attribute enough for a safe login form?

Tags: javascript, html

I this in my HTML(notice the `required` at the end of the tag):

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
```

I am using Node.js to sign in into MySQL. Within my login controller when I am signing in on click of a button, is it necessary to use something like this?

```
//Get values from HTML
var {email} = req.body;

//If email is empty
if(!email) {
  return res.status(400).render('login', {
   message: 'Please provide an email and password') //Provide a message on the HTML template
   });
}
```

Or is not worth using this JavaScript code at all when there is a `required` attribute in the HTML code?

Or is it safe to use both for security purposes?

Comment: you can do validation in your frontend page and then you can send the data to the server, it saves time and data consume,

Comment: @CodeBug Meaning just using `Required` is absolutely fine?

Comment: It’s not necessary, and it doesn’t provide *any* true validation as that *must* be done on the server side. But you should still use it for usability because it helps your users know what they have to do and makes it quicker and easier for them.

Comment: ya absolutely fine, and here you're doing login stuff so you must have to validate email and password, so only required is fine.

Comment: "required" is front-end and prevents the form from being submitted if it is not valid. You shouldn't make it to the javascript portion if you have required. However, if you want further validation than the required and ``type="email"`` can provide, then add JS

Comment: *Meaning just using Required is absolutely fine?* - that is a definite **no**! Validation must *always* be carried out on server side because client side validation can easily be disabled by users. As for additional JS, you can tailor error messages to be more informative in js, and you will often need more complex validation than just required or not.

Comment: @CodeBug No. If `undefined` is passed to some function that expects an password, the code might do something unexpected and give access to other people's accounts.

Comment: @D.Pardal That's exactly what I was thinking.. if somehow, something random occurs and potentially they can access somebody else's account.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I suppose the `required` is literally only used for indication if user missed a field out? Nothing to do with security pruposes.

Comment: Yes, that’s it exactly! As I said, it’s easy to bypass any validation or security on the webpage itself. It’s good to do for the users benefit but it does nothing for you :) And that applies to *all* client side validation, including JavaScript.

Comment: @FluffyKitten That makes a lot of sense now - I didn't even think about the Google Chrome Developer console aha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***must always*** verify the data on the server. The `required` attribute is merely an indication to the browser that it should not let the user submit the form without filling that field, but *nothing* stops the user from submitting the form using JavaScript via DevTools or even directly making a request to the server.

**The `required` attribute does not provide any security whatsoever.**

However, you don't need to provide an error message from the server if the code you send to the browser already handles those errors. A `400` status code is enough.